# SMS verification : what if user phone number changed?

Tags: security, sms-verification

I’m building an application and I’m thinking about asking user phone number to send a  verification SMS. Though, imagine if the phone number is cancelled and attributed later to someone else. Then, the new person would be able to connect to my app in the name of the old one... 
So is there any way to prevent this behavior ? 
I want to make it like tinder : sign up possible by 2 different ways : (facebook connection and phone number) or (phone number and mail)

I have another question : I see that many sms sending services are not free (all of them actually). If I make an api with these services, anyone can send a lot of http request to it and make me pay 0,05€ times 100000000 ? And I can’t rely on IP adresses because with 3G an ip is not associated with a particular person...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To your first question:**

You are describing *Two Step Authentication* (aka *Two Step Verification*) which you can read about in the Wikipedia page: [Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication):

> a method of confirming a user's claimed identity by utilizing something they know (password) and a second factor other than something they have or something they are. An example of a second step is the user repeating back something that was sent to them through an out-of-band mechanism.

You are correct that a phone number can change owners (as can an email address though over a longer time period on average). You are using their phone number as that out-of-band mechanism described above.

If the user has recently authenticated with their password, when you send the user an out-of-band code and they re-type that into an input box you have some degree of confidence that the end user both knows the password and has access to the SMS message and are choosing to trust that association.

You will need to consider if, and for how long, you can trust that association within the security context of the use case.

For example, adding two step verification when detecting the end-user has just authenticated on a device you have never seen before is a nice additional protection. However, using the out-of-band SMS verification in account recover could open up a big security hole. You do not want to bypass the authentication with something they know (password) in a password reset flow by simply having access to that SMS number. SMS is also not an appropriate mechanism for one-time-password (OTP).

If you want to offer you users more protections on their accounts look into implementing true MFA with software tokens (eg. [Google Authenticator](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator), [Authy](https://authy.com/), etc.) and hard tokens (eg. [FIDO U2F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_2nd_Factor) devices such as [Yubikey](https://www.yubico.com/), [Google Titan](https://store.google.com/us/product/titan_security_key_kit?hl=en-US), etc.).

**To your second question:**

You are correct, IP-based limiting is insufficient. With SMS services you are likely going to be making a server-side API call to the SMS provider. First check to see what security features your provider has out of the box. Next, protect *your* endpoint that is triggering the API calls to the SMS provider.

- Rate limit the number of SMS messages to any one given recipient (eg. no more than X SMS messages to a single number per Y minute window)
- Rate limit the number of SMS messages one person can make to different numbers (eg. no more than X different phone numbers per user per day).
- Do not allow unauthenticated requests. The user should have already completed the first authentication step (something they know eg. username/password) before performing the out-of-band SMS step.
- Protect the SMS form from [Cross Site Forgery Requests (CSFR)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)). Your back-end should only make the API call to the SMS provider if it knows the request came from your front-end and not another host.
- Protect the SMS form from bot attacks. There are many approaches with [Google ReCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3) being one of the more common.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) does oAuth has sth to do with 2 step verification ?